ros2 can't view topics from remote raspberry pi in virtual machine
I have a problem where I can't see topics published on my Raspi 4 in my VMWare Virtual Machine.
I remember being able to see the topics while my work environment was on a dual-boot setup but that machine broke down so I had to set up my work environment again and I opted for a VM this time but now when I go in Rviz2 I can't see any of the topics published on the Raspi anymore.
I can ping the Raspi from my VM but I can't ping my VM from the Raspi. I'm not very good at networking so I wouldn't know what more information to post here so please feel free to ask for anything.
If anyone knows a solution for this, I'd be very grateful.

This gist was written for ROS 1, but I think it should get you 90% there for ROS 2 as well: https://gist.github.com/chfritz/8c2adab45a94e091be77c55b0432ad2e

As a sanity check, are you sure that ping isn't blocked by a firewall on the VM? Sometimes it is. This, What port does 'ping' work on?, might help (although it's not quite the link that I was looking for).
